# How to make a stored procedure parameter backwards compatible?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, parameters, parameter-passing

I have a stored procedure that accepted the following parameters:

```
@ExecutionID INT,    
@Status_Name VARCHAR(50),
```

We needed to change the procedure so it accepts multiple IDs, not just `ExecutionID`, so now the parameters look like this:

```
@Id INT, 
@Status_Name VARCHAR(50),  
@IdType BIT = 0 --0 for ExecutionID and 1 for InsertID)

SELECT TOP 1 @Status_Curent = [' + @Status_Name + '_Status] 
FROM [Database].[dbo].[StoredProcedure] 
WHERE [' + CASE WHEN COALESCE(@IdType, 0) = 0 THEN 'Execution' ELSE 'Insert' END + 'ID] = ' + CAST(@Id AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' 
ORDER BY [' + @Status_Name + '_Status] DESC
```

But we still have other projects that run the old procedure. How can I default the `@ExecutionID` to run as if it were the `@Id` so we don't have to change the other projects?

So far I have this:

```
DECLARE @Status_Name VARCHAR(50) = 'Food',
        @IdType BIT = 0,
        @Id INT = NULL,
        @ExecutionID INT = 6045

IF (@ExecutionID != NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @Id = @ExecutionID
END

SELECT @Id
```

or

```
SET @Id = CASE WHEN @ExecutionID != NULL THEN @ExecutionID ELSE @Id END
```

But they still return NULL.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: You can **NEVER** compare `NULL` with regular equality or inequality operators  - you can **only** check `@ExecutionID IS NULL` or `@ExecutionID IS NOT NULL` .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compare a variable with `NULL` using the usual equality or inequality operators - those would always return `NULL` / undefined.

You need to use `@ExecutionID IS NULL` or `@ExecutionID IS NOT NULL` exclusively - so try this instead:

```
DECLARE @Status_Name VARCHAR(50) = 'Food',
        @IdType BIT = 0,
        @Id INT = NULL,
        @ExecutionID INT = 6045

IF (@ExecutionID IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @Id = @ExecutionID
END

SELECT @Id
```

and

```
SET @Id = CASE 
              WHEN @ExecutionID IS NOT NULL 
                  THEN @ExecutionID 
                  ELSE @Id 
          END
```